# sql - How can I count the differences of two rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
Item    ProviderId

Item1   1

Item1   2

Item2   1

Item3   1
```

I wish to get a new table. In the new table, it only lists the `item`s who has at least two different `ProviderId`s.

So in the above example, since only `item1` has two different `ProviderId` I wish to get table like this:

```
Item

Item1
```

How can I write the statement to do this?

Comment: what flavour of sql or is this a generic question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `group by` and `having`:

```
select item
from table
group by item
having count(distinct ProviderId)>=2
```

or without `distinct`

```
select item
from tab
group by item, ProviderId
having count(1)>=2;
```

### [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a4a58/5/0) demo

With query as table:

```
select item
from (select item, ptoviderId from tabA) as tab
group by item, ProviderId
having count(1)>=2;
```

If you want to create new table, you can use `into`:

```
select item
into newTable
from table
-- or (select item, ptoviderId from tabA)
group by item
having count(distinct ProviderId)>=2
```

Comment: The condition should be > 1, he wants 2 or more

Comment: Having count( distinct ProviderId ) >= 2

Comment: What if the table (item, providerid) also comes from a select join?

Comment: @JacksonTale I added one more solution.

Comment: Thanks for the one more solution

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 SELECT [Item]      
      FROM [TABLE_NAME]
      GROUP BY [Item]
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ProviderId) >1
    GO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO <your new table> (newTableItem)
    (SELECT Item
    FROM <table>
    GROUP BY Item
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ProviderId) > 1)-- or just HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 if one Item can't have two times the same ProviderId
```

Comment: @danihp oh, you're right, if one Item can have two times the same providerId, which doesn't make sense, I think (but I might be wrong)

Comment: you are right. Only has sense if N:M relationship has more attributes like 'price' and 'date' ...

Comment: What if the table (item, providerid) also comes from a select join?